# best way to show more than one page consecutively on a dashboard

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've a number of items not less than 200 items in the worst case. I would like to show all of them on a screen "dashBoard", but the screen can't show all of them one time. the idea is use a gridView to have a group different than the next each time. the page will remain shown for 30 seconds. this way I can show all of them within five or more pages during 150 seconds.

my question what is the best technique to do this? using more than one page, more than one gridview in the same page, or same page but create the gridview @ run time etc...

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use a pager on the gridview and timer to cycle through the pages, and perhaps a checkbox to turn the auto-cycle on/off?

Comment: @Bandar..Use gridview ti display items for specific duration and also you can use pagination

Answer (score 0):

I would use a framework like [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) to bind an array of items to a template. You may not want to have all of the items in the DOM at the same time or it could be slow, thus one of these frameworks could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

As I presume you will be cycling all the results more than once I think you should load all the results and generate the gridview runtime.

I would recommend looking into https://datatables.net/ . It's a gridview library in javascript which does everything you want and more.